# Scaling down of parts

Tags: modeling, objects

I wonder what he does at the 3:40 mark of this video to scale down all the parts at the same time while separating them?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liNGmdXsfbs

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, Blender uses the median point of all selected objects to use the transform tools on:

[image: Median Point]

You can change this to individual origins to scale down each selected object individually.

[image: Individual origins]